# How to add photos to iPhone Simulator from Mac OS X?

Tags: mac, iphone

I have already stored many photos on my Mac, which I want to add it on my iPhone Simulator, which is required to test my application.

How do I add photos to the Photos application on the iPhone Simulator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open the Window in mac where your images are stored.

Open your simulator another side.

Now drag your image from mac window to simulator,

simulator will open safari, and in a safari tab your image will be shown.

Tap & press down on image in simulator,

There will be message to "save image",

save image.

It will be added to your iPhone simulator.

Comment: Wouldn't it be odd to get a "turnaround" badge for a self-answered question?

Comment: I answered a day after. I found the answer from SO.